# CustomerClassLoader: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, class, classloader

I have been playing around with a CustomerClassLoader as i am trying to load a .class file into `JUnitCore.runClasses(...);` but i am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SimpleTest (wrong name: JUnit/SimpleTest)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
at Java.CustomClassLoader.access$000(CustomClassLoader.java:16)
at Java.CustomClassLoader$1.run(CustomClassLoader.java:45)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at Java.CustomClassLoader.findClass(CustomClassLoader.java:33)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
.....
```

I don't know what it wrong as I am passing in the correct class name and path for the class. here is the code that i am using

CustomClassLoader

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.AccessControlContext;
import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction;

public class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

String repoLocation = "C:/TempBINfolder/bin/JUnit/";

public CustomClassLoader() { }

public CustomClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
super(parent);
}

@Override
protected Class<?> findClass(final String name)
throws ClassNotFoundException {

AccessControlContext acc = AccessController.getContext();

try {
return (Class)AccessController.doPrivileged(
 new PrivilegedExceptionAction() {
  public Object run() throws ClassNotFoundException {

   FileInputStream fi = null;
   try {

    String path = name.replace('.', '/');
    fi = new FileInputStream(repoLocation + path
      + ".class");
    byte[] classBytes = new byte[fi.available()];
    fi.read(classBytes);
    return defineClass(name, classBytes, 0,
      classBytes.length);
   }catch(Exception e )
   {
    throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);
   }
  }
 }, acc);
} catch (java.security.PrivilegedActionException pae) {
return super.findClass(name);
}
}
}
```

And this is how i am calling it

```
ClassLoader cls= new CustomClassLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
Class stringClass = null;
    try {
        stringClass = cls.loadClass("SimpleTest");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CompilerForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        stringClass.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CompilerForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CompilerForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    JUnitCore.runClasses(stringClass);
```

Does anyone know why i am getting this error?

Comment: Is your class defined in package JUnit? If so, can you remove it and give a try? Or change String repoLocation = "C:/TempBINfolder/bin/JUnit/"; to String repoLocation = "C:/TempBINfolder/bin/";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`stringClass = cls.loadClass("SimpleTest");` 

to 
`stringClass = cls.loadClass("JUnit.SimpleTest");`

(i.e Add the fully qualified package name of the class file)

and

`String repoLocation = "C:/TempBINfolder/bin/JUnit/";`

to 
`String repoLocation = "C:/TempBINfolder/bin/";`

Comment: this does get rid of all my errors, but when i run it now and if i put a break point inside `SimpleTest.java` it never hits the break point... as there is no errors i don't know if it is working or not, do you have any ideas?

Comment: It should hit the break point if in the same eclipse project. If project is different, try adding that project in the "source" section of the run/debug configuration used to run the above.

Comment: just to understand it, why did I have to take JUnit out of the location and put it into the loadClass()?

Comment: Since the class loader expects the fully qualified name - as shown in the error `(wrong name: JUnit/SimpleTest)` we need to give that, `JUnit.SimpleTest` . But when we give that, this part of the code ` String path = name.replace('.', '/');
    fi = new FileInputStream(repoLocation + path
      + ".class");` causes the class file to be searched inside of folder JUnit..so we remove JUnit from the repoLocation.

Answer (score 0):

You must be declaring your SimpleTest class to be in JUnit package, but you are trying to load is as simply SimpleTest (no package).  Try eiteher:

1. remove the package declaration
2. remove Junit from location: `String repoLocation = "C:/TempBINfolder/bin/";`

Answer (score 0):

Class name should be fully qualified `junit.samples.SimpleTest`

```
    stringClass = cls.loadClass("SimpleTest");
```

should be

```
    stringClass = cls.loadClass("junit.sample.SimpleTest");
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes this happens to me, and usually it's solved by a clean and build. If that doesn't work, I usually restart my IDE.